# select with sum of column values grouping by day

Tags: php, mysql, date, sum

I have a table with columns datetime, order value, and number of pieces for each order issued. Datetime is in standard datetime mysql format.

To get the total sum of orders, I have a query like this:

```
$sqlsum = "SELECT SUM(order_value) FROM orders";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlsum)) {
    $resultsum = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlsum);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsum)) {
        $total_sales = $row['SUM(order_value)'];

        // and here I use the value in a simple report
    }
}
```

To get a report of all single orders, usually I'd do like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $order_time = $row["datetime"];
        $order_value = $row["order_value"];
        $pieces_number = $row["pieces"];

        // and here I use the results in a detailed report
    }
}
?>
```

Now I have to make two different reports, one for each day and one for each month, and each one has to show:
- count of orders
- sum of order values
- sum of number of pieces
How should be the query to get the count of orders per day and the sum of values and pieces per day?

Googled the site for similar issues, but didn't find a post with a clear solution for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 1st case you need to group by day using the [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(datetime) day, 
  COUNT(*) orderscounter,
  SUM(order_value) valuesum,
  SUM(pieces) piecessum
FROM orders
GROUP BY day
```

In the 2nd case you need to group by year/month using the [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(datetime) year,
  MONTH(datetime) month, 
  COUNT(*) orderscounter,
  SUM(order_value) valuesum,
  SUM(pieces) piecessum
FROM orders
GROUP BY year, month
```

Comment: I'n not enough familiar wth certain query syntax. If I well understand, the word after the brackets is a sort of key-name, and I have to group by key and not by value. Right?

Comment: These are aliases for the columns. You can use them in the `group by` clause, although you can also use: `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)` and  `GROUP BY YEAR(datetime), MONTH(datetime)`

Comment: How would you put result in variables? I'm following your suggestion but get errors like "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given..."

Comment: You asked for queries. I can't help you with php.

Comment: It's running ; )